Do native speakers say "the highest height", "the longest length", or "the deepest depth", etc?
Do native speakers say "the highest height", "the longest length", or "the deepest depth", etc?
I find these expressions repetitive, but I don't know how else to express them.
Does using adjectives like "greatest" or "biggest" work?
P.S. I'm trying to compare the lengths of different subway systems in major cities in the world. The London one is the longest, hence the wondering if native speakers say something like:

The London subway is the system with the longest total track length.


The only one of these I particularly dislike is "highest height". "Longest length" and "deepest depth" do not bother me in the same way but I can not explain why.

Fascinating, @SoronelHaetir, because my reactions are the perfect complement of yours. But the only reason I can accept highest height is that, as Charles B. Cannon says in his answer, it’s idiomatic. Otherwise, things like length and mass are (for me) to be understood as they are formulated in SI (informally known as the metric system). Thus a price cannot be expensive or cheap. It can be steep or piddling, high or low. Likewise, temperature cannot be hot or cold, but high or low. It is objects at high temperature that are hot, not the temperature itself.

"The highest height" doesn't tell you anything.  I suggest giving the context, such as "the highest hill", "the longest mission", or "the deepest ocean". Others will work too: "the steepest gradient", "the greatest area", etc

Plurals, highest heights, deepest depths, longest lengths all strike my ear as OK.

@PaulTanenbaum Tanenbaum : I was thinking of it being part of something like "highest heights of Everest", "deepest depths of the Marianas Trench". The only length one I can come up with right now is "longest length of the interstate highway system without an exit". The former bugs me but the latter two do not. And like I said, I can not really explain why. Actually, the highway one does bug me a little, but not nearly as much as the heights example.

I would say "...the greatest total track length". (NB 'Etc" is short for et cetera (Latin for 'and all the rest'), so it doesn't need full stops between the letters.)

highest heights does not work. We say: The greatest heights. There simply is no doubt about this. [The longest stretch of an interstate highway, not length]

Native speakers do not normally say "the highest height" or "the deepest depth" or "the longest length" because the superlative  form can itself be noun-like :

The highest I've ever climbed is 7,000 meters.
The deepest I've ever dived is 30 meters.
The longest I've ever held my breath is two minutes.

P.S. In response to the clarification now given in the question:
Don't feel compelled to find a label for everything, something like total track length.  You need labels for charts and table column headers but they are not necessary in your summary, where you have the natural language at your disposal.

The London subway system has the most track, at  ____  miles.


I've edited my question to give a clearer context. Is there any adjective that works in that situation, or is rephrasing my sentence a must?

@KenAdams I've added a P.S. now that you've clarified.

I tend to use "greatest" in these situtations, but "highest height", at least, is an idiom I seem to remember having encountered. "Biggest" is not correct in any circumstances, in my view.

How do you extract the meaning of "the greatest mountain?" In terms of its height, is mass, its renown...? And what's wrong with biggest?

Maybe the poster means "the greatest height", which is what I would have suggested.

The Christian worship song "Indescribable" (by Chris Tomlin) begins with these lyrics:

From the highest of heights to the depths of the sea,
Creation's revealing your majesty.

In the right context, all of the examples in the OP are valid. It's certainly true that, as the other answers and comments point out, "highest height" and "longest length" are often simplified. But if the focus is on the lengths, heights and depths themselves and differences are being compared, comparative and superlative words are perfectly ok.
